# MERISE: How to link a Table with an Already association table that representing Many-to-Many relationship between Two Tables

Tags: database-design, data-modeling

in my MCD i have this Relation:

- Adherent_Movement is the association table representing the many-to-many relationship between Adherent and Book.
- Borrowing_Movement and Returning_Movement are tables representing the specific movements related to borrowing and returning books.
  ============
  Adherent_Movement_ID in Borrowing_Movement and Returning_Movement tables are foreign keys referencing the ID column in the Adherent_Movement table After MLD is done!, establishing the relationship between these tables and a not ready yet Table is a big problem here!.
  ============
  Note: the PrimaryKey of the Adherent_Movement table After MLD is done is the ID column and not the foreign keys of book and adherent tables!
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1Wsp.png)

i add link with that association and two future tables..